# env: node: No such file or directory in phpstorm when compiling less

Tags: node.js, npm, less, phpstorm

I'm trying to compile my `main.less` file to a `main.css` file using phpstorm. However, I'm getting this error and the `.less` file does not compile.

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc main.less
env: node: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

I'm using a mac and not sure why this is happening. It was working fine before, but I restarted my computer and now I'm getting this error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: Try to make symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems Node is not found in your PATH. PHPStorm normally uses your environment variables to figure out tools locations. But on MacOSX the environment variables differ between GUI applications and within the terminal. PHPStorm tries to load terminal environment on startup by executing the following command on startup:

-l -i -c '/Applications/PHPStorm.app/bin/printenv.py'

Seems this command either fails or can't retrieve all needed stuff.
Can you check if the problem persists when running PHPStorm from system terminal (open -a /Applications/PHPStorm.app)?
And one more thing to check: please open your Less file watcher settings, press ellipsis button in 'Environment variables' field to view variables - do you have 'Include parent environment variables' enabled? If this option is disabled, system environment variables won't be available to file watcher

Comment: I uninstalled node and re installed. The problem seems to be fixed. however if I run into it again I will try this solution. Thank you lena

Comment: Running PyCharm from the terminal worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem with uglify-js but it's the same thing. Turned out to be caused by using nvm, which nests the node root. 
Fixed it by following @funivan comment to create a symlink pointing to my (default) node version under nvm.

`sudo ln -s /home/[usr]/.nvm/versions/node/[v8.9.1]/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

Answer (score 3):

This was happening to me because I had node installed via `nvm`, and `nvm` installed via homebrew, which is not officially supported. I deleted `nvm` completely and reinstalled it using the [official install script](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script), reinstalled node via `nvm`, and the error went away.

See [nvm is not compatible with the npm config “prefix” option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774067/2397068) for more information.

Comment: This did not work for me. @radu_m's answer did though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I upgraded to Monterey OSX. I could see the ENV path in my file watcher in phpstorm was not matching my terminal command line path. So I updated PHPStorm and then the correct ENV path was showing up in PHPStorm and everything worked again. So broke by an OS upgrade and fixed by PHPStorm upgrade.