# nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option:

Tags: node.js, npm, prefix, nvm

I am trying to run another NodeJS version with `nvm` but getting this error:

```
$ nvm use v4.2.4

nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: 
   currently set to "/Users/z/.npm-global"
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.2.4` to unset it.
```

I have my prefix set on purpose to avoid `sudo npm` (see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Is there any way I can use `nvm` without losing my prefix for globally installed packages?

Comment: I use **npm config delete prefix** to get around this, no problem so far

Comment: @DanWhite If I delete prefix, I lose diverting my global installs into dedicated directory.

Comment: (nvm maintainer here) That's the point. With nvm, it, not you, manages your global installs. Separately, global installs should never be shared across node versions.

Comment: @LJHarb Thank you for taking time to comment! It would be great if `nvm` could manage the installs as you point. However, it looks like it fails to do so by itself, asking me instead to delete my prefix. Why can't the `nvm` simply override that setting as long as it is active? So the `nvm` would use its own settings, and I can keep my previous working state when I exit `nvm` to return to my regular node version.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev because it's an npm setting, and nvm can't control where npm looks for config. There's no way I know of for nvm to override npm's setting in a per-shell way, and I didn't want to automatically delete the prefix (thus changing your settings destructively) without the user's explicit consent.

Comment: @LJHarb I was assuming the `nvm` would replace the current node and the `npm` for the chosen version with `nvm use <version>`. Then the new `npm` would have its own setting, a sort of "override" but better ;). That way, the new `npm` would not even "know" about the old prefix, so the problem shouldn't even exist. Or does the `nvm` only replace the node but keeps the old `npm` (which would be confusing imo)? I was also assuming the switch to selected node version was not per-shell, was it?

Comment: Each copy of node comes with its own npm, which determines its own settings.

Comment: Indeed, each selected node version with nvm is per-shell - that's by design.

Comment: I had this error message after have set myself npm to install avoiding sudo myself, following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212175/npm-yeoman-install-generator-angular-without-sudo/18277225#18277225. I wonder then if that type of "workaround" is recommended and if fixing the local prefix as the accepted answer here will make me able to both install local package without sudo and have the prefix "fiexed". Also another concern is about the fact that the suggested solution i used create a ".node" folder that could interferwith "node" in unix system

Comment: @LJHarb please answer this simple binary question: does the discussed limitation effectively beat us back to having to install global packages with sudo, OR does it SOLVE this problem in its own way (i.e. installing global packages with nvm does NOT require sudo)?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski it obviates the need to use sudo, because the place global npm modules are installed (`npm root -g`) is located inside your HOME directory - which you don't need sudo to modify.

Separately, the ecosystem at large strongly discourages installing ANYTHING globally, so this problem shouldn't really pop up in modern usage anyways.

Answer (score 535, accepted):

## Delete and Reset the prefix

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```

---

*Note: Change the version number with the one indicated in the error message.*

> nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently
>   set to "/usr/local" Run "npm config delete prefix" or "nvm use
>   --delete-prefix v6.11.1 --silent" to unset it.

---

Credits to @gabfiocchi on Github - ["You need to overwrite nvm prefix"](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/855#issuecomment-314309706)

Comment: This worked like a charm! Just had to grab my node version.

Comment: I seemed to have a symbolic link /usr/local/bin/node that would cause integrated terminal in vscode to see a node version it shouldn't have seen. Following the steps above and then deleting the symbolic link appears to have fixed the issue. My node and npm are governed by nvm now

Comment: this works perfect.

just do not miss to set prefix the node version, you are going to use.

`npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/<node-version-directory>`

Comment: This only works in the current window. If you open a new shell or a new window you have to do it all over again.

Comment: Personally, I just had to run the first command to delete the prefix: `npm config delete prefix`. I recently upgrade node from version 7 to version 10.

Comment: Just deleting it should be fine.  However, if set, it should be to `$NVM_DIR/current`.

Comment: I have to do these in order. 1. nvm use --delete-prefix vx.x.x --silent   2. npm config delete prefix 
3. npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/vx.x.x

Comment: I could not run `npm` because I got error `nvm is not compatible`. So at first run I did `nvm use --delete-prefix ...`. Then I could run `npm config delete` and `npm config set`

Comment: @jtiscione I got rid of this from happening when opening a new shell by deleting a rogue `$HOME/.nvmrc`

Comment: @saylestyler delete folder without an explanation does not seems to me advisable

Comment: @CarmineTambascia yes my bad! i meant i deleted a $PATH edit in a *rc file!

Comment: `npm use` after

Comment: What I don't understand about this solution is how manually setting the version fits with the use of nvm. If the whole point of nvm is to be able to dynamically shift between version based on context, then the need to manually set the version seems to negate that.

Comment: Not on mac though.

Comment: after running the commands:
```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```
calling `nvm use` now doesn't update node version. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 84):

I had the same problem and executing `npm config delete prefix` did not help me.

But this did:

After installing nvm using brew, create `~/.nvm` directory:
`$ mkdir ~/.nvm`

and add following lines into `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
. $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

(Check that you have no other nvm related command in any `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`)

Open a new terminal and this time it should not print any warning message.
Check that nvm is working by executing `nvm --version` command.
After that, install/reinstall NodeJS using `nvm install node && nvm alias default node`.

**More Info**

I installed `nvm` using `homebrew` and after that I got this notification:

> Please note that upstream has asked us to make explicit managing
>      nvm via Homebrew is unsupported by them and you should check any
>      problems against the standard nvm install method prior to reporting.
>
> You should create NVM's working directory if it doesn't exist:
>
> ```
>  mkdir ~/.nvm
> ```
>
> Add the following to `~/.bash_profile` or your desired shell
>      configuration file:
>
> ```
>  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
>  . $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
> ```
>
> You can set `$NVM_DIR` to any location, but leaving it unchanged from
>      `/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.31.0` will destroy any nvm-installed Node installations
>      upon upgrade/reinstall.

Ignoring it brought me to this error message:

> `nvm` is not compatible with the `npm config` "prefix" option: currently set to `"/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.31.0/versions/node/v5.7.1"`
>      Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v5.7.1 --silent` to unset it.

I followed an earlier guide (from `homebrew/nvm`) and after that I found that I needed to reinstall NodeJS. So I did:

```
nvm install node && nvm alias default node
```

and it was fixed.

**Update:**
Using brew to install NVM causes slow startup of the Terminal. You can [follow this instruction](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1277#issuecomment-447495610) to resolve it.

Comment: Fwiw I had to `export NVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.31.0` (instead of `~/.nvm`)

Comment: `nvm alias default node` seemed to helped me in my case

Comment: (nvm maintainer here) `nvm` is not supported when installed via brew. Please uninstall it and use the proper method, the curl script in the readme.

Comment: I used the curl script to install `nvm`.  This answer did not work for me.

Comment: @intcreator Did you find a solution that did?

Comment: @JakeT. it's been so long I don't remember.  I upvoted Mick's answer, so maybe that worked, but if it did I don't know why I commented on this one...

Comment: @intcreator Thanks. I ended up doing a complete fresh install of node using nvm based on this guide: https://www.nearform.com/blog/how-to-manage-node-js-sudo-free-with-nvm/ And my hangup ended up being that I had previously installed using homebrew, which is no longer supported. It left a lot of remnants that took a while to clear, and then I had to `rm -rf node_modules` and run `npm install` again, since the directories already had screwy permissions issues.

Comment: For the clarity of posterity, I had to do a `brew remove node -f`, which removes all installed versions. Do this first, then follow the guide in my link above, then remove node_modules. You should get a clean install! I think you then have to install npm as well, which I just followed the instructions from a nodejs.org article that popped up when I searched for it. `npm install npm@latest -g` was the command, once you install node.

Comment: @LJHarb [nvm maintainer] instruction is working for me. install using curl

Comment: Thank you! The following worked for me:
"nvm install node && nvm alias default node"

Comment: the brew --prefix syntax here was crucial for me -- trying to run the nvm.sh directly produced a prefix complaint, and wouldn't set the node version.

Comment: I recently was playing with Apple's GPTK and that changed my `.bash_profile` and added this line: `eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"` which caused the issue with `nvm` and `prefix`. The trick to delete prefix via command was okay but it wasn't permanent obviously. I simply deleted that line from `.bash_profile` and now everything is back to nornal.

Answer (score 40):

This may be a conflict with your local installation of Node (if you had it installed via another way than NVM in the past). You should delete this instance of node:

1. remove node_modules

   `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
2. remove node

   `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node`
3. remove node link

   `cd /usr/local/bin && ls -l | grep "../lib/node_modules/" | awk '{print $9}'| xargs rm`

After you cant install nvm

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation? The comments are not enough, because your commandlines are more intricate than explained by them. Elaborate why the details of your answer solve the problem. Contrast your answer against the years older answers. What makes your answer an added value to this question?

Comment: For me, the empty first code line (which you recently added) needs its own explanation...

Comment: After five months on StackOverflow, consider taking the very enlightening guided help [tour].

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: "After you cant install nvm"  So, if my goal is to use nvm, I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Removing the node links is what did it for me (stray `npm` symlink was hanging around).

Comment: Some explanation would definitely help. `nvm` works fine for me, after following the above steps and yes, it works in new terminals (even those within webstorm & vscode).

Answer (score 37):

This error can occur when your **NVM installation folder path** has a **Symbolic Link**.

### Explanation

The default installation path of NVM is: `$HOME/.nvm` but your home folder could be a symbolic link for another drive, like my case.

Example, my home folder is a Symbolic Link to aother drive:

`/home/myuser -> /bigdrive/myuser`

This cause the prefix problem.

### Solution

On your startup script (.bashrc or .zshrc or other), change the NVM folder to the direct path.

Ex: `NVM_DIR="/bigdrive/myuser/.nvm"`.

.bashrc

```
export NVM_DIR="/bigdrive/myuser/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer should have more visibility

Comment: Nope. I fried my brain to understand this crazy error. I didn't find any posts that helped me. I had to fight hard to solve the problem. I am happy to help you. Vote on my answer to be more visible.

Comment: my echod $NVM_DIR was "/Users/vijayshanker/.nvm" should i put "export NVM_DIR="/Users/vijayshanker/.nvm(and the rest)" in bashrc, tried but it still did not fixed it, been struggling for 6 hours, please help note:i don't have npm installed, i did not installed my node from npm

Comment: one solution maybe to export NVM_DIR=$(readlink -f "$HOME/.nvm") in .bashrc or command line. This will remove all symlink from $HOME/.nvm and export a plain full path with only real directories.

Comment: `export HOME="/big/drive/myuser"` This should be more resilient. though for your situation, i would just use fstab to bind mount it. I might go that route if this causes any more issues.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this while using node installed via `nvm`, with `nvm` installed via homebrew. I solved it by running `brew uninstall nvm`, `rm -rf $NVM_DIR`, then reinstalling nvm using the [official install script](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) and reinstalling the node version I needed.

Note: I also had `$NVM_DIR` mounted and symlinked. I moved it back into my homedir.

Answer (score 10):

It might be the problem if you have your home directory mounted somewhere, due nvm does not work properly with symlinks. Because I don't care where is my $NVM_DIR located I run this and all works fine:

```
$ mv ~/.nvm /tmp/
$ export NVM_DIR="/tmp/.nvm"
$ nvm use --delete-prefix v6.9.1
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]I had the same problem and it was really annoying each time with the terminal. I run the command to the terminal and it was fixed

For those try to remove nvm from brew

it may not be enough to just brew uninstall nvm

if you see npm prefix is still /usr/local, run this command

> sudo rm -rf
>   /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}

Answer (score 7):

I have the same error message but other solution.
The autogenerated path during curl (install.sh) does not match.
Check this with:

```
echo $NVM_DIR
```

In my case: `/var/www//.nvm`. Show in your auto generated bash file and change it and replace it:  (~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.bashrc)

replace

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
```

with (e.g.)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME.nvm"
```

Comment: Came here to put the same comment :) In my case was because when I created the user I set the home as useradd --home /home/user/ with the trailing / I removed from the /etc/passwd file and everything start working again

Answer (score 5):

There are just two commands to resolve this issue.
Some users may also be getting the error as soon as they are also opening the terminal. The first thing they see is this error:

```
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: 
currently set to "/Users/z/.npm-global"
```

Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.2.4` to unset it.

So to resolve this issue, Run the following two commands.
Note: Change the version number as the same they are showing in your error.

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```

Note: This will also work if your terminal is using zsh.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem when it was showing on VSCode and JetBrains Terminals, but not in the native terminal using the following commands:

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep "np[mx]"
```

This will give you the resolved path at the end:

```
... npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
... npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

From there, removing the files and relaunching VS Code should fix the issue:

```
rm -R /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
rm -R /usr/local/bin/npx /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

fix link: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1690#issuecomment-392014774

Answer (score 2):

I've tried every answer in this thread but none worked. Reinstalling `nvm` as documented https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm with `curl` fixed my problem.

Comment: wow, this saved me an epoch of time. all I did was run this and was back up and running!


      `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

Answer (score 1):

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861348/2391795 answer but it didn't work out well.

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```

After running the recommended commands my nvm didn't work anymore, running `nvm use` would display the proper node version being used, but running `node -v` would show another. It wasn't possible to change node's version anymore.

I uninstalled and reinstalled nvm entirely to fix it. I followed https://github.com/creationix/nvm#manual-uninstall by running

```
$ rm -rf "$NVM_DIR"
```

Then edited my `.zshrc` to remove the lines related to nvm, which in my case were

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Then started a new shell (so that nvm isn't loaded in this new shell) and ran https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

Which added nvm the lines I previously had removed in my `.zshrc`.

Then I was able to use nvm as I used to. I guess that's an odd case were things went wrong and forced me to reinstall everything, doesn't look like most people go through this due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe my situation.

First, check the current config

```
$ nvm use --delete-prefix v10.7.0
$ npm config list
```

Then, I found the error config in output:

```
; project config /mnt/c/Users/paul/.npmrc
prefix = "/mnt/c/Users/paul/C:\\Program Files\\nodejs"
```

So, I deleted the `C:\\Program Files\\nodejs` in /mnt/c/Users/paul/.npmrc.

Answer (score 1):

For those who first installed node via homebrew and then added nvm to a system.

If you see noisy message : `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local` you may need to delete the node_modules and node itself, the solution was perfectly described above^^, but below is simple way.

Since brew automatically added env var to .bash_profile, each time bash loaded path points to the originally installed version.

1.Go to ./.bash_profile
2. Comment on line which points to node, like so
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"

next time bash should load node which is installed by nvm,
make sure bash_profile contains nvm dir
export NVM_DIR="/Users/{your_user_name}/.nvm"

Answer (score 1):

Following sh file helped my case

```bash
# nvmish.sh
unset npm_config_prefix
source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use 18
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for the nvm prefix problem a found this question(before finding the solution). Here is my shell "dialog". I hope, it can be usefull for somebody. I was able to set to prefix with the help of this post:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6592

When I tried `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix` before using `npm --prefix="" set prefix ""`, I got only:
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Note that you will have to repeat the same procedure with every node version, the prefix is set back to (in my case) /usr/local after installation.

```
    $ nvm install 0.10
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
    nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"
    Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.44` to unset it.
    $ npm --prefix="" set prefix ""
    $ nvm use 0.10.44
    nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/home/john"
    Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.44` to unset it.
    $ nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.44
    Now using node v0.10.44 (npm v1.3.10)
    $ nvm ls
    v0.10.44
             v4.4.3
    ->       system
    default -> 4.4.3 (-> v4.4.3)
    node -> stable (-> v4.4.3) (default)
    stable -> 4.4 (-> v4.4.3) (default)
    iojs -> N/A (default)
    $ npm config get prefix
    /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after moving my home folder to a new drive on linux. It was fixed by removing .nvm folder and reinstalling nvm

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the issue. I symlinked `$HOME/.nvm` to `$DEV_ZONE/env/node/nvm` directory. I was facing same issue. I replaced `NVM_DIR` in `$HOME/.zshrc` as follows

```
export NVM_DIR="$DEV_ZONE/env/node/nvm"
```

BTW, please install NVM using `curl` or `wget` command not by using `brew`. For more please check the comment in this issue on Github: **[855#issuecomment-146115434](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/855#issuecomment-146115434)**

Comment: What about installing `nvm` with `npm`?

Comment: Installing nvm through homebrew is officially deprecated and leads to issues due to some incompatibilities. The official way is to use curl/wget, see https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script see https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/298#issuecomment-152255091
Installing through npm isn't supported AFAIK, because nvm installs npm, so if npm also installs nvm it can lead to edge cases. You can read about it on the issue I previously linked.

Answer (score 0):

I just have a idea. Use the symbolic link to solve the error and you can still use your prefix for globally installed packages.

`ln -s [your prefix path]  [path in the '~/.nvm']`

then you will have a symbolic folder in the `~/.nvm` folder, but in fact, your global packages are still installed in [your prefix path]. Then the error will not show again and you can use `nvm use **` normally.
ps: it's worked for me on `mac`.
pps: do not forget to set `$PATH` to your npm `bin` folder to use the globally installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me I removed the lines

```sh
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"

PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
```

From my `.bashrc` and was able to run `npm install -g package-name` without needing `sudo` permissions or having the error message appear in my shell window.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, This is because of conflicting the npm of node and nodejs

so remove nodejs by below commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

this will remove all nodejs related Packages,

after the above command, you have to run autoremove command just like that

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

this will solve the problem,

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and worked for me

1- sudo su

2-`root@antonio:/home/antonio# mv ~/.nvm /tmp/`

3- `root@antonio:/home/antonio# export NVM_DIR="/tmp/.nvm"`

4- `root@antonio:/home/antonio# nvm use --delete-prefix v17.4.0`

5- `root@antonio:/home/antonio# node -v

[image]`

Answer (score -3):

Note:
to remove, delete, or uninstall nvm - just remove the `$NVM_DIR` folder (usually `~/.nvm`)
you can try :
`rm -rf ~/.nvm`