# Where should I "unset" an incompatible prefix option for nvm in my macOS Travis config?

Tags: macos, npm, travis-ci, nvm

At the top of my [Travis job for macOS](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/441117679), under "Worker Information" I get

```
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.10.0 --silent` to unset it.
```

What are the implications of this (e.g. can I simply ignore) and where in [my `travis.yml`](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.travis.yml) should I run the suggested command?

Note that I do not see this warning for my Linux jobs in the same project.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option) describes the warning in more detail, but it's not clear to me how to use that information in this context.