# VSCode nvm complaining about a prefix option when the Integrated Terminal is launched

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, nvm

nvm (Node Version Manager) users often see this error for the first time inside VS Code's Integrated Terminal:

```
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v8.12.0 --silent` to unset it
```

According to the solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/integrated-terminal.md#why-is-nvm-complaining-about-a-prefix-option-when-the-integrated-terminal-is-launched

I have to find the old npm install path first then run "which npm" before it.

But where is the nvm initialization script and how to run "which npm" before it, just add line at the beginning of the script? Is there any other way to fix the problem?

Comment: Solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option?answertab=oldest#tab-top) thread works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

run this

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v8.12.0
```

solution is from [nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Just be sure to update the prefix if you update your node version with nvm since global packages will reinstall in the old (prefixed) directories despite adding a `--reinstall-packages-from` flag

Answer (score 1):

Setting `debug.node.autoAttach` to `disabled` worked for me

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I'd actually broken it by setting this.