# zsh throws npm errors when starting up because npm and nvm conflict

Tags: npm, nvm

I installed `serverless` framework to create some infrastructure code. I needed to update my version of `npm` after I udpated I now get this error message every time `zsh` starts.

This does not happen with `sh` or `bash`.

```
garrett ~ % zsh
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:2
module.exports = async process => {
                       ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v6.9.2 --silent` to unset it.
garrett ~ % npm -v
8.15.0
garrett ~ % nvm --version
0.35.3
garrett ~ % cat .zshrc
source ~/.bash_profile
PS1='garrett %~ %# '

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"

garrett ~ % cat .bash_profile
# Added by ./setup - se_profile
# export SE_SHELL=bash
alias python="python3"
alias pip="pip3"
source "/Users/USER/Software/sportsengine/bin/se_profile"

export LSCOLORS="Exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"
alias ls='ls -alGH'

alias notify='terminal-notifier -title "Terminal" -message "Done with task! Exit status: $?"' -activate com.apple.Terminal
```

After researching, the advice on this post does not work [nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option#:%7E:text=Delete%20and%20Reset%20the%20prefix)

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```

I also followed the steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option#:%7E:text=This%20may%20be%20a%20conflict%20with%20your%20local%20installation%20of%20Node%20(if%20you%20had%20it%20installed%20via%20another%20way%20than%20NVM%20in%20the%20past).%20You%20should%20delete%20this%20instance%20of%20node%3A)

> This may be a conflict with your local installation of Node (if you had it installed via another way than NVM in the past). You should delete this instance of node:
>
> remove node_modules  `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
>
> remove node `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node`
>
> remove node link  `cd /usr/local/bin && ls -l | grep "../lib/node_modules/" | awk '{print$9}'| xargs rm` After you cant install nvm

Although the error message is gone, I no longer have `npm` installed.

When I install `npm` with `brew install npm` I'm at the same problem outlined above.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `source ~/.bash_profile` inside your `.zshrc` file? Zsh code is not a superset of bash code. No wonder your Zsh is acting weirdly.

Comment: @MarlonRichert still learning obviously. thanks for the advice.